# Issue with Exim4

Tags: server, email, exim

I think I've pulled out the rest of the hair I have. I currently have a CentOS machine that I am moving everything to Ubuntu.

My biggest holdback is email. I have exim4 on both machines. I could probably copy the config file from the CentOS machine to Ubuntu but I really need to start fresh.

I have local emails working however, when I send emails to remote domains I get the following error: Mailing to remote domains not supported.

I wanted to use the regular exim4 config however, with all of the various parts, it can become a little daunting for this novice. I took the compiled config file and changed it to exim4.conf and made a number of changes. The file can be found at the below link.

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ijlel92jn99gjst4k8sjt/putty.txt?rlkey=zyfsp3smh5uzbq5bikvc2tzqv&dl=0

```
# Generated config

exim_path = /usr/sbin/exim4

.ifndef CONFDIR
CONFDIR = /etc/exim4
.endif

UPEX4CmacrosUPEX4C = 1
##############################################
# the following macro definitions were created
# dynamically by /usr/sbin/update-exim4.conf
.ifndef MAIN_LOCAL_INTERFACES
MAIN_LOCAL_INTERFACES=<; 127.0.0.1 ; 192.168.X.Y
.endif
.ifndef MAIN_PACKAGE_VERSION
MAIN_PACKAGE_VERSION=4.95-4ubuntu2.2
.endif
.ifndef MAIN_LOCAL_DOMAINS
MAIN_LOCAL_DOMAINS=@:localhost:myhost:mydomain.com
.endif
.ifndef MAIN_RELAY_TO_DOMAINS
MAIN_RELAY_TO_DOMAINS=
.endif
.ifndef ETC_MAILNAME
ETC_MAILNAME=myhost
.endif
.ifndef LOCAL_DELIVERY
LOCAL_DELIVERY=mail_spool
.endif
.ifndef MAIN_RELAY_NETS
MAIN_RELAY_NETS='127.0.0.1 : 192.168.X.0/24'
.endif
.ifndef DCreadhost
DCreadhost=
.endif
.ifndef DCsmarthost
DCsmarthost='smarthost.mailrelay.com::2525'
.endif
.ifndef DC_eximconfig_configtype
DC_eximconfig_configtype=smarthost
.endif
.ifndef DCconfig_local
DCconfig_local=1
.endif
##############################################

daemon_smtp_ports = 25 : 465 : 587

domainlist local_domains = @ : mydomain.com : alpha.mydomain.com : beta.mydomain.com : myhost.mydomain.com

domainlist relay_to_domains = 

hostlist relay_from_hosts = 127.0.0.1 : 192.168.X.0/24

.ifndef MAIN_PRIMARY_HOSTNAME_AS_QUALIFY_DOMAIN
.ifndef MAIN_QUALIFY_DOMAIN
qualify_domain = mydomain.com
.else
qualify_domain = mydomain.com
.endif
.endif

.ifdef MAIN_LOCAL_INTERFACES
local_interfaces = MAIN_LOCAL_INTERFACES
.endif

.ifndef LOCAL_DELIVERY
LOCAL_DELIVERY=mail_spool
.endif

gecos_pattern = ^([^,:]*)
gecos_name = $1

.ifndef MAIN_LOG_SELECTOR
MAIN_LOG_SELECTOR = +smtp_protocol_error +smtp_syntax_error +tls_certificate_verified +tls_peerdn
.endif

.ifndef MAIN_ACL_CHECK_MAIL
MAIN_ACL_CHECK_MAIL = acl_check_mail
.endif
acl_smtp_mail = MAIN_ACL_CHECK_MAIL

.ifndef MAIN_ACL_CHECK_RCPT
MAIN_ACL_CHECK_RCPT = acl_check_rcpt
.endif
acl_smtp_rcpt = MAIN_ACL_CHECK_RCPT

.ifndef MAIN_ACL_CHECK_DATA
MAIN_ACL_CHECK_DATA = acl_check_data
.endif
acl_smtp_data = MAIN_ACL_CHECK_DATA

.ifdef MESSAGE_SIZE_LIMIT
message_size_limit = MESSAGE_SIZE_LIMIT
.endif

.ifdef MAIN_ALLOW_DOMAIN_LITERALS
allow_domain_literals
.endif

.ifndef DC_minimaldns
.ifndef MAIN_HOST_LOOKUP
MAIN_HOST_LOOKUP = *
.endif
host_lookup = MAIN_HOST_LOOKUP
.endif

dns_dnssec_ok = 1

.ifdef MAIN_HARDCODE_PRIMARY_HOSTNAME
primary_hostname = MAIN_HARDCODE_PRIMARY_HOSTNAME
.endif

prdr_enable = true

.ifdef MAIN_SMTP_ACCEPT_MAX_NOMAIL_HOSTS
smtp_accept_max_nonmail_hosts = MAIN_SMTP_ACCEPT_MAX_NOMAIL_HOSTS
.endif

.ifndef MAIN_FORCE_SENDER
local_from_check = false
local_sender_retain = true
untrusted_set_sender = *
.endif

.ifndef MAIN_IGNORE_BOUNCE_ERRORS_AFTER
MAIN_IGNORE_BOUNCE_ERRORS_AFTER = 2d
.endif
ignore_bounce_errors_after = MAIN_IGNORE_BOUNCE_ERRORS_AFTER

.ifndef MAIN_TIMEOUT_FROZEN_AFTER
MAIN_TIMEOUT_FROZEN_AFTER = 7d
.endif
timeout_frozen_after = MAIN_TIMEOUT_FROZEN_AFTER

.ifndef MAIN_FREEZE_TELL
MAIN_FREEZE_TELL = postmaster
.endif
freeze_tell = MAIN_FREEZE_TELL

.ifndef SPOOLDIR
SPOOLDIR = /var/spool/exim4
.endif
spool_directory = SPOOLDIR

.ifndef MAIN_TRUSTED_USERS
MAIN_TRUSTED_USERS = uucp
.endif
trusted_users = MAIN_TRUSTED_USERS
.ifdef MAIN_TRUSTED_GROUPS
trusted_groups = MAIN_TRUSTED_GROUPS
.endif

.ifdef MAIN_KEEP_ENVIRONMENT
keep_environment = MAIN_KEEP_ENVIRONMENT
.else
keep_environment =
.endif
.ifdef MAIN_ADD_ENVIRONMENT
add_environment = MAIN_ADD_ENVIRONMENT
.endif

.ifdef _OPT_MAIN_SMTPUTF8_ADVERTISE_HOSTS
.ifndef MAIN_SMTPUTF8_ADVERTISE_HOSTS
MAIN_SMTPUTF8_ADVERTISE_HOSTS =
.endif
smtputf8_advertise_hosts = MAIN_SMTPUTF8_ADVERTISE_HOSTS
.endif

.ifdef MAIN_TLS_ENABLE
.ifndef MAIN_TLS_ADVERTISE_HOSTS
MAIN_TLS_ADVERTISE_HOSTS = *
.endif
tls_advertise_hosts = MAIN_TLS_ADVERTISE_HOSTS

# MAIN_TLS_CERTKEY = /etc/exim4/mailcert

MAIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE = /etc/exim4/exim.crt
MAIN_TLS_PRIVATEKEY = /etc/exim4/exim.key

.ifdef MAIN_TLS_CERTKEY
tls_certificate = MAIN_TLS_CERTKEY
.else
.ifndef MAIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE
MAIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE = CONFDIR/exim.crt
.endif
tls_certificate = MAIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE

.ifndef MAIN_TLS_PRIVATEKEY
MAIN_TLS_PRIVATEKEY = CONFDIR/exim.key
.endif
tls_privatekey = MAIN_TLS_PRIVATEKEY
.endif

.ifndef MAIN_TLS_VERIFY_CERTIFICATES
MAIN_TLS_VERIFY_CERTIFICATES = ${if exists{/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt}\
                                    {/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt}\
                    {/dev/null}}
.endif
tls_verify_certificates = MAIN_TLS_VERIFY_CERTIFICATES

.ifdef MAIN_TLS_VERIFY_HOSTS
tls_verify_hosts = MAIN_TLS_VERIFY_HOSTS
.endif

.ifdef MAIN_TLS_TRY_VERIFY_HOSTS
tls_try_verify_hosts = MAIN_TLS_TRY_VERIFY_HOSTS
.endif

.else
.endif

.ifdef MAIN_LOG_SELECTOR
log_selector = MAIN_LOG_SELECTOR
.endif

begin acl

acl_local_deny_exceptions:
  accept
    hosts = ${if exists{CONFDIR/host_local_deny_exceptions}\
                 {CONFDIR/host_local_deny_exceptions}\
                 {}}
  accept
    senders = ${if exists{CONFDIR/sender_local_deny_exceptions}\
                   {CONFDIR/sender_local_deny_exceptions}\
                   {}}
  accept
    hosts = ${if exists{CONFDIR/local_host_whitelist}\
                 {CONFDIR/local_host_whitelist}\
                 {}}
  accept
    senders = ${if exists{CONFDIR/local_sender_whitelist}\
                   {CONFDIR/local_sender_whitelist}\
                   {}}

  .ifdef LOCAL_DENY_EXCEPTIONS_LOCAL_ACL_FILE
  .include LOCAL_DENY_EXCEPTIONS_LOCAL_ACL_FILE
  .endif
  
  .ifdef WHITELIST_LOCAL_DENY_LOCAL_ACL_FILE
  .include WHITELIST_LOCAL_DENY_LOCAL_ACL_FILE
  .endif

acl_check_mail:

  accept

.ifndef CHECK_RCPT_LOCAL_LOCALPARTS
CHECK_RCPT_LOCAL_LOCALPARTS = ^[.] : ^.*[@%!/|`#&?]
.endif

.ifndef CHECK_RCPT_REMOTE_LOCALPARTS
CHECK_RCPT_REMOTE_LOCALPARTS = ^[./|] : ^.*[@%!`#&?] : ^.*/\\.\\./
.endif

acl_check_rcpt:

  accept
    hosts = :
    control = dkim_disable_verify

.ifdef DC_minimaldns
  warn
    control = dkim_disable_verify
.else
.ifdef DISABLE_DKIM_VERIFY
  warn
    control = dkim_disable_verify
.endif
.endif

  .ifdef CHECK_RCPT_LOCAL_LOCALPARTS
  deny
    domains = +local_domains
    local_parts = CHECK_RCPT_LOCAL_LOCALPARTS
    message = restricted characters in address
  .endif

  

  .ifdef CHECK_RCPT_REMOTE_LOCALPARTS
  deny
    domains = !+local_domains
    local_parts = CHECK_RCPT_REMOTE_LOCALPARTS
    message = restricted characters in address
  .endif

  accept
    .ifndef CHECK_RCPT_POSTMASTER
    local_parts = postmaster
    .else
    local_parts = CHECK_RCPT_POSTMASTER
    .endif
    domains = +local_domains : +relay_to_domains

  .ifdef CHECK_RCPT_VERIFY_SENDER
  deny
    !acl = acl_local_deny_exceptions
    !verify = sender
    message = Sender verification failed
  .endif

  deny
    !acl = acl_local_deny_exceptions
    senders = ${if exists{CONFDIR/local_sender_callout}\
                         {CONFDIR/local_sender_callout}\
                   {}}
    !verify = sender/callout

  .ifndef CHECK_RCPT_NO_FAIL_TOO_MANY_BAD_RCPT

  deny    condition     = ${if and {\
                        {>{$rcpt_count}{10}}\
                        {<{$recipients_count}{${eval:$rcpt_count/2}}} }}
          message       = Rejected for too many bad recipients
          logwrite      = REJECT [$sender_host_address]: bad recipient count high [${eval:$rcpt_count-$recipients_count}]
  .endif

  accept
    hosts = +relay_from_hosts
    control = submission/sender_retain
    control = dkim_disable_verify

  accept
    authenticated = *
    control = submission/sender_retain
    control = dkim_disable_verify

  require
    message = relay not permitted
    domains = +local_domains : +relay_to_domains

  require
    verify = recipient

  deny
    !acl = acl_local_deny_exceptions
    recipients = ${if exists{CONFDIR/local_rcpt_callout}\
                            {CONFDIR/local_rcpt_callout}\
                      {}}
    !verify = recipient/callout

  deny
    !acl = acl_local_deny_exceptions
    senders = ${if exists{CONFDIR/local_sender_blacklist}\
                   {CONFDIR/local_sender_blacklist}\
                   {}}
    message = sender envelope address $sender_address is locally blacklisted here. If you think this is wrong, get in touch with postmaster
    log_message = sender envelope address is locally blacklisted.

  deny
    !acl = acl_local_deny_exceptions
    hosts = ${if exists{CONFDIR/local_host_blacklist}\
                 {CONFDIR/local_host_blacklist}\
                 {}}
    message = sender IP address $sender_host_address is locally blacklisted here. If you think this is wrong, get in touch with postmaster
    log_message = sender IP address is locally blacklisted.

  .ifdef CHECK_RCPT_REVERSE_DNS
  warn
    condition = ${if and{{def:sender_host_address}{!def:sender_host_name}}\
                      {yes}{no}}
    add_header = X-Host-Lookup-Failed: Reverse DNS lookup failed for $sender_host_address (${if eq{$host_lookup_failed}{1}{failed}{deferred}})
  .endif

  .ifdef CHECK_RCPT_SPF
  deny
    !acl = acl_local_deny_exceptions
    condition = ${run{/usr/bin/spfquery.mail-spf-perl --ip \
                   ${quote:$sender_host_address} --identity \
                   ${if def:sender_address_domain \
                       {--scope mfrom  --identity ${quote:$sender_address}}\
                       {--scope helo --identity ${quote:$sender_helo_name}}}}\
                   {no}{${if eq {$runrc}{1}{yes}{no}}}}
    message = [SPF] $sender_host_address is not allowed to send mail from \
              ${if def:sender_address_domain {$sender_address_domain}{$sender_helo_name}}.
    log_message = SPF check failed.

  defer
    !acl = acl_local_deny_exceptions
    condition = ${if eq {$runrc}{5}{yes}{no}}
    message = Temporary DNS error while checking SPF record.  Try again later.

  warn
    condition = ${if <={$runrc}{6}{yes}{no}}
    add_header = Received-SPF: ${if eq {$runrc}{0}{pass}\
                                {${if eq {$runrc}{2}{softfail}\
                                 {${if eq {$runrc}{3}{neutral}\
                  {${if eq {$runrc}{4}{permerror}\
                   {${if eq {$runrc}{6}{none}{error}}}}}}}}}\
                } client-ip=$sender_host_address; \
                ${if def:sender_address_domain \
                   {envelope-from=${sender_address}; }{}}\
                helo=$sender_helo_name

  warn
    condition = ${if >{$runrc}{6}{yes}{no}}
    log_message = Unexpected error in SPF check.
  .endif

  .ifdef CHECK_RCPT_IP_DNSBLS
  warn
    dnslists = CHECK_RCPT_IP_DNSBLS
    add_header = X-Warning: $sender_host_address is listed at $dnslist_domain ($dnslist_value: $dnslist_text)
    log_message = $sender_host_address is listed at $dnslist_domain ($dnslist_value: $dnslist_text)
  .endif

  .ifdef CHECK_RCPT_DOMAIN_DNSBLS
  warn
    !senders = ${if exists{CONFDIR/local_domain_dnsbl_whitelist}\
                    {CONFDIR/local_domain_dnsbl_whitelist}\
                    {}}
    dnslists = CHECK_RCPT_DOMAIN_DNSBLS
    add_header = X-Warning: $sender_address_domain is listed at $dnslist_domain ($dnslist_value: $dnslist_text)
    log_message = $sender_address_domain is listed at $dnslist_domain ($dnslist_value: $dnslist_text)
  .endif

  .ifdef CHECK_RCPT_LOCAL_ACL_FILE
  .include CHECK_RCPT_LOCAL_ACL_FILE
  .endif

  accept
    domains = +relay_to_domains
    endpass
    verify = recipient

  accept

acl_check_data:

  .ifndef IGNORE_SMTP_LINE_LENGTH_LIMIT
  deny
    condition  = ${if > {$max_received_linelength}{998}}
    message    = maximum allowed line length is 998 octets, \
                       got $max_received_linelength
  .endif

  .ifndef NO_CHECK_DATA_VERIFY_HEADER_SYNTAX
  deny
    !acl = acl_local_deny_exceptions
    !verify = header_syntax
    message = header syntax
    log_message = header syntax ($acl_verify_message)
  .endif

  .ifdef CHECK_DATA_VERIFY_HEADER_SENDER
  deny
    !acl = acl_local_deny_exceptions
    !verify = header_sender
    message = No verifiable sender address in message headers
  .endif

  .ifdef CHECK_DATA_LOCAL_ACL_FILE
  .include CHECK_DATA_LOCAL_ACL_FILE
  .endif

  accept

begin routers

.ifdef MAIN_ALLOW_DOMAIN_LITERALS
domain_literal:
  debug_print = "R: domain_literal for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = ipliteral
  domains = ! +local_domains
  transport = remote_smtp
.endif

hubbed_hosts:
  debug_print = "R: hubbed_hosts for $domain"
  driver = manualroute
  domains = "${if exists{CONFDIR/hubbed_hosts}\
                   {partial-lsearch;CONFDIR/hubbed_hosts}\
              fail}"
  same_domain_copy_routing = yes
  route_data = ${lookup{$domain}partial-lsearch{CONFDIR/hubbed_hosts}}
  transport = remote_smtp

.ifdef DCconfig_internet

dnslookup_relay_to_domains:
  debug_print = "R: dnslookup_relay_to_domains for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = dnslookup
  domains = ! +local_domains : +relay_to_domains
  transport = remote_smtp
  same_domain_copy_routing = yes
  no_more

.ifndef ROUTER_DNSLOOKUP_IGNORE_TARGET_HOSTS
ROUTER_DNSLOOKUP_IGNORE_TARGET_HOSTS = <; 0.0.0.0 ; 127.0.0.0/8 ; 192.168.0.0/16 ; 172.16.0.0/12 ; 10.0.0.0/8 ; 169.254.0.0/16 ; 255.255.255.255 ; ::/128 ; ::1/128 ; fc00::/7 ; fe80::/10 ; 100::/64
.endif

dnslookup:
  debug_print = "R: dnslookup for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = dnslookup
  domains = ! +local_domains
  transport = remote_smtp
  same_domain_copy_routing = yes
  ignore_target_hosts = ROUTER_DNSLOOKUP_IGNORE_TARGET_HOSTS
  no_more

.endif

.ifdef DCconfig_local
nonlocal:
  debug_print = "R: nonlocal for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = redirect
  domains = ! +local_domains
  allow_fail
  data = :fail: Mailing to remote domains not supported
  no_more

.endif

.ifdef DCconfig_smarthost DCconfig_satellite

smarthost:
  debug_print = "R: smarthost for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = manualroute
  domains = ! +local_domains
  transport = remote_smtp_smarthost
  route_list = * DCsmarthost byname
  host_find_failed = ignore
  same_domain_copy_routing = yes
  no_more

.endif

COND_LOCAL_SUBMITTER = "\
               ${if match_ip{$sender_host_address}{:@[]}\
                    {1}{0}\
        }"

real_local:
  debug_print = "R: real_local for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = accept
  domains = +local_domains
  condition = COND_LOCAL_SUBMITTER
  local_part_prefix = real-
  check_local_user
  transport = LOCAL_DELIVERY

system_aliases:
  debug_print = "R: system_aliases for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = redirect
  domains = +local_domains
  allow_fail
  allow_defer
  data = ${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/aliases}}
  .ifdef SYSTEM_ALIASES_USER
  user = SYSTEM_ALIASES_USER
  .endif
  .ifdef SYSTEM_ALIASES_GROUP
  group = SYSTEM_ALIASES_GROUP
  .endif
  .ifdef SYSTEM_ALIASES_FILE_TRANSPORT
  file_transport = SYSTEM_ALIASES_FILE_TRANSPORT
  .endif
  .ifdef SYSTEM_ALIASES_PIPE_TRANSPORT
  pipe_transport = SYSTEM_ALIASES_PIPE_TRANSPORT
  .endif
  .ifdef SYSTEM_ALIASES_DIRECTORY_TRANSPORT
  directory_transport = SYSTEM_ALIASES_DIRECTORY_TRANSPORT
  .endif

.ifdef DCconfig_satellite
hub_user:
  debug_print = "R: hub_user for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = redirect
  domains = +local_domains
  data = ${local_part}@DCreadhost
  check_local_user

hub_user_smarthost:
  debug_print = "R: hub_user_smarthost for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = manualroute
  domains = DCreadhost
  transport = remote_smtp_smarthost
  route_list = * DCsmarthost byname
  host_find_failed = ignore
  same_domain_copy_routing = yes
  check_local_user
.endif

userforward:
  debug_print = "R: userforward for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = redirect
  domains = +local_domains
  check_local_user
  file = $home/.forward
  require_files = $local_part_data:$home/.forward
  no_verify
  no_expn
  check_ancestor
  allow_filter
  forbid_smtp_code = true
  directory_transport = address_directory
  file_transport = address_file
  pipe_transport = address_pipe
  reply_transport = address_reply
  skip_syntax_errors
  syntax_errors_to = real-$local_part@$domain
  syntax_errors_text = \
    This is an automatically generated message. An error has\n\
    been found in your .forward file. Details of the error are\n\
    reported below. While this error persists, you will receive\n\
    a copy of this message for every message that is addressed\n\
    to you. If your .forward file is a filter file, or if it is\n\
    a non-filter file containing no valid forwarding addresses,\n\
    a copy of each incoming message will be put in your normal\n\
    mailbox. If a non-filter file contains at least one valid\n\
    forwarding address, forwarding to the valid addresses will\n\
    happen, and those will be the only deliveries that occur.

procmail:
  debug_print = "R: procmail for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = accept
  domains = +local_domains
  check_local_user
  transport = procmail_pipe
  require_files = ${local_part_data}:\
                  ${if exists{/etc/procmailrc}\
                    {/etc/procmailrc}{${home}/.procmailrc}}:\
                  +/usr/bin/procmail
  no_verify
  no_expn

maildrop:
  debug_print = "R: maildrop for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = accept
  domains = +local_domains
  check_local_user
  transport = maildrop_pipe
  require_files = ${local_part_data}:${home}/.mailfilter:+/usr/bin/maildrop
  no_verify
  no_expn

.ifndef FIRST_USER_ACCOUNT_UID
FIRST_USER_ACCOUNT_UID = 0
.endif

.ifndef DEFAULT_SYSTEM_ACCOUNT_ALIAS
DEFAULT_SYSTEM_ACCOUNT_ALIAS = :fail: no mail to system accounts
.endif

COND_SYSTEM_USER_AND_REMOTE_SUBMITTER = "\
               ${if and{{! match_ip{$sender_host_address}{:@[]}}\
                        {<{$local_user_uid}{FIRST_USER_ACCOUNT_UID}}}\
                    {1}{0}\
        }"

lowuid_aliases:
  debug_print = "R: lowuid_aliases for $local_part@$domain (UID $local_user_uid)"
  check_local_user
  driver = redirect
  allow_fail
  domains = +local_domains
  condition = COND_SYSTEM_USER_AND_REMOTE_SUBMITTER
  data = ${if exists{CONFDIR/lowuid-aliases}\
              {${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{CONFDIR/lowuid-aliases}\
              {$value}{DEFAULT_SYSTEM_ACCOUNT_ALIAS}}}\
              {DEFAULT_SYSTEM_ACCOUNT_ALIAS}}

local_user:
  debug_print = "R: local_user for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = accept
  domains = +local_domains
  check_local_user
  local_parts = ! root
  transport = LOCAL_DELIVERY
  cannot_route_message = Unknown user

mail4root:
  debug_print = "R: mail4root for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = redirect
  domains = +local_domains
  data = /var/mail/mail
  file_transport = address_file
  local_parts = root
  user = mail
  group = mail

begin transports

.ifdef HIDE_MAILNAME
REMOTE_SMTP_HEADERS_REWRITE=*@+local_domains $1@DCreadhost frs : *@ETC_MAILNAME $1@DCreadhost frs
REMOTE_SMTP_RETURN_PATH=${if match_domain{$sender_address_domain}{+local_domains}{${sender_address_local_part}@DCreadhost}{${if match_domain{$sender_address_domain}{ETC_MAILNAME}{${sender_address_local_part}@DCreadhost}fail}}}
.endif

.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_HELO_FROM_DNS
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_HELO_DATA
REMOTE_SMTP_HELO_DATA==${lookup dnsdb {ptr=$sending_ip_address}{$value}{$primary_hostname}}
.else
REMOTE_SMTP_HELO_DATA=${lookup dnsdb {ptr=$sending_ip_address}{$value}{$primary_hostname}}
.endif
.endif

.ifndef REMOTE_SMTP_SMARTHOST_TLS_VERIFY_HOSTS
  REMOTE_SMTP_SMARTHOST_TLS_VERIFY_HOSTS = *
.endif

address_file:
  debug_print = "T: address_file for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = appendfile
  delivery_date_add
  envelope_to_add
  return_path_add

address_pipe:
  debug_print = "T: address_pipe for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = pipe
  return_fail_output

address_reply:
  debug_print = "T: autoreply for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = autoreply

mail_spool:
  debug_print = "T: appendfile for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = appendfile
  file = /var/mail/$local_part_data
  delivery_date_add
  envelope_to_add
  return_path_add
  group = mail
  mode = 0660
  mode_fail_narrower = false

maildir_home:
  debug_print = "T: maildir_home for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = appendfile
  .ifdef MAILDIR_HOME_MAILDIR_LOCATION
  directory = MAILDIR_HOME_MAILDIR_LOCATION
  .else
  directory = $home/Maildir
  .endif
  .ifdef MAILDIR_HOME_CREATE_DIRECTORY
  create_directory
  .endif
  .ifdef MAILDIR_HOME_CREATE_FILE
  create_file = MAILDIR_HOME_CREATE_FILE
  .endif
  delivery_date_add
  envelope_to_add
  return_path_add
  maildir_format
  .ifdef MAILDIR_HOME_DIRECTORY_MODE
  directory_mode = MAILDIR_HOME_DIRECTORY_MODE
  .else
  directory_mode = 0700
  .endif
  .ifdef MAILDIR_HOME_MODE
  mode = MAILDIR_HOME_MODE
  .else
  mode = 0600
  .endif
  mode_fail_narrower = false

maildrop_pipe:
  debug_print = "T: maildrop_pipe for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = pipe
  path = "/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin"
  command = "/usr/bin/maildrop"
  message_prefix =
  message_suffix =
  return_path_add
  delivery_date_add
  envelope_to_add

procmail_pipe:
  debug_print = "T: procmail_pipe for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = pipe
  path = "/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin"
  command = "/usr/bin/procmail"
  return_path_add
  delivery_date_add
  envelope_to_add

remote_smtp:
  debug_print = "T: remote_smtp for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = smtp
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_HOSTS_AVOID_TLS
  hosts_avoid_tls = REMOTE_SMTP_HOSTS_AVOID_TLS
.endif
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_HEADERS_REWRITE
  headers_rewrite = REMOTE_SMTP_HEADERS_REWRITE
.endif
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_RETURN_PATH
  return_path = REMOTE_SMTP_RETURN_PATH
.endif
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_HELO_DATA
  helo_data=REMOTE_SMTP_HELO_DATA
.endif
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_INTERFACE
  interface = REMOTE_SMTP_INTERFACE
.endif
.ifdef DKIM_DOMAIN
dkim_domain = DKIM_DOMAIN
.endif
.ifdef DKIM_IDENTITY
dkim_identity = DKIM_IDENTITY
.endif
.ifdef DKIM_SELECTOR
dkim_selector = DKIM_SELECTOR
.endif
.ifdef DKIM_PRIVATE_KEY
dkim_private_key = DKIM_PRIVATE_KEY
.endif
.ifdef DKIM_CANON
dkim_canon = DKIM_CANON
.endif
.ifdef DKIM_STRICT
dkim_strict = DKIM_STRICT
.endif
.ifdef DKIM_SIGN_HEADERS
dkim_sign_headers = DKIM_SIGN_HEADERS
.endif
.ifdef DKIM_TIMESTAMPS
dkim_timestamps = DKIM_TIMESTAMPS
.endif
.ifdef TLS_DH_MIN_BITS
tls_dh_min_bits = TLS_DH_MIN_BITS
.endif
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE
tls_certificate = REMOTE_SMTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE
.endif
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_PRIVATEKEY
tls_privatekey = REMOTE_SMTP_PRIVATEKEY
.endif
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_HOSTS_REQUIRE_TLS
  hosts_require_tls = REMOTE_SMTP_HOSTS_REQUIRE_TLS
.endif
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_TRANSPORTS_HEADERS_REMOVE
  headers_remove = REMOTE_SMTP_TRANSPORTS_HEADERS_REMOVE
.endif

remote_smtp_smarthost:
  debug_print = "T: remote_smtp_smarthost for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = smtp
  multi_domain
  hosts_try_auth = <; ${if exists{CONFDIR/passwd.client} \
        {\
        ${lookup{$host}nwildlsearch{CONFDIR/passwd.client}{$host_address}}\
        }\
        {} \
      }
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_SMARTHOST_HOSTS_AVOID_TLS
  hosts_avoid_tls = REMOTE_SMTP_SMARTHOST_HOSTS_AVOID_TLS
.endif
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_SMARTHOST_HOSTS_REQUIRE_TLS
  hosts_require_tls = REMOTE_SMTP_SMARTHOST_HOSTS_REQUIRE_TLS
.endif
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_SMARTHOST_TLS_VERIFY_CERTIFICATES
  tls_verify_certificates = REMOTE_SMTP_SMARTHOST_TLS_VERIFY_CERTIFICATES
.endif
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_SMARTHOST_TLS_VERIFY_HOSTS
  tls_verify_hosts = REMOTE_SMTP_SMARTHOST_TLS_VERIFY_HOSTS
.endif
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_HEADERS_REWRITE
  headers_rewrite = REMOTE_SMTP_HEADERS_REWRITE
.endif
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_RETURN_PATH
  return_path = REMOTE_SMTP_RETURN_PATH
.endif
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_HELO_DATA
  helo_data=REMOTE_SMTP_HELO_DATA
.endif
.ifdef TLS_DH_MIN_BITS
tls_dh_min_bits = TLS_DH_MIN_BITS
.endif
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_SMARTHOST_TLS_CERTIFICATE
tls_certificate = REMOTE_SMTP_SMARTHOST_TLS_CERTIFICATE
.endif
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_SMARTHOST_PRIVATEKEY
tls_privatekey = REMOTE_SMTP_SMARTHOST_PRIVATEKEY
.endif
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_TRANSPORTS_HEADERS_REMOVE
  headers_remove = REMOTE_SMTP_TRANSPORTS_HEADERS_REMOVE
.endif
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_SMARTHOST_PROTOCOL
  protocol = REMOTE_SMTP_SMARTHOST_PROTOCOL
.endif

address_directory:
  debug_print = "T: address_directory for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = appendfile
  delivery_date_add
  envelope_to_add
  return_path_add
  check_string = ""
  escape_string = ""
  maildir_format

begin retry

*                      *           F,2h,15m; G,16h,1h,1.5; F,4d,6h

begin rewrite

.ifndef NO_EAA_REWRITE_REWRITE
*@+local_domains "${lookup{${local_part}}lsearch{/etc/email-addresses}\
                   {$value}fail}" Ffrs
*@ETC_MAILNAME "${lookup{${local_part}}lsearch{/etc/email-addresses}\
                   {$value}fail}" Ffrs
.endif

begin authenticators

cram_md5:
  driver = cram_md5
  public_name = CRAM-MD5
  client_name = ${extract{1}{:}{${lookup{$host}nwildlsearch{CONFDIR/passwd.client}{$value}fail}}}
  client_secret = ${extract{2}{:}{${lookup{$host}nwildlsearch{CONFDIR/passwd.client}{$value}fail}}}

PASSWDLINE=${sg{\
                ${lookup{$host}nwildlsearch{CONFDIR/passwd.client}{$value}fail}\
            }\
            {\\N[\\^]\\N}\
            {^^}\
        }

plain:
  driver = plaintext
  public_name = PLAIN
.ifndef AUTH_CLIENT_ALLOW_NOTLS_PASSWORDS
  client_send = "<; ${if !eq{$tls_out_cipher}{}\
                    {^${extract{1}{:}{PASSWDLINE}}\
             ^${sg{PASSWDLINE}{\\N([^:]+:)(.*)\\N}{\\$2}}\
           }fail}"
.else
  client_send = "<; ^${extract{1}{:}{PASSWDLINE}}\
            ^${sg{PASSWDLINE}{\\N([^:]+:)(.*)\\N}{\\$2}}"
.endif

login:
  driver = plaintext
  public_name = LOGIN
.ifndef AUTH_CLIENT_ALLOW_NOTLS_PASSWORDS
  client_send = "<; ${if and{\
                          {!eq{$tls_out_cipher}{}}\
                          {!eq{PASSWDLINE}{}}\
                         }\
                      {}fail}\
                 ; ${extract{1}{::}{PASSWDLINE}}\
         ; ${sg{PASSWDLINE}{\\N([^:]+:)(.*)\\N}{\\$2}}"
.else
  client_send = "<; ${if !eq{PASSWDLINE}{}\
                      {}fail}\
                 ; ${extract{1}{::}{PASSWDLINE}}\
         ; ${sg{PASSWDLINE}{\\N([^:]+:)(.*)\\N}{\\$2}}"
.endif
```